# Managed C++ wrapper around a static library

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli, wrapper

I am using Visual Studio, .Net and Windows.

I am writing a wrapper around a static library. The problem I need help with is the error message:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Unmanaged.lib'

"Unmanaged" is a class **in** my project but it is not the project's name.

I created a C++ CLR Class Library project. In it I created a managed class and an unmanaged class. The unmanaged class calls the static library. The managed class uses the unmanaged class. The compiler and linker seem to be trying to create a library for the unmanaged class, but that is not what should happen.

Can I have an unmanaged class (that is used only by the managed class) in a managed class library project? I assume so but if I am wrong then it will save me time to know that what I am trying to do will not work.

Comment: Are you sure there's no "Unmanaged.lib" in Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies? If not, search for #pragma comment(lib, "Unmanaged.lib").

Comment: So you have a static library that you want to link into the managed assembly.  Where is it located?  What is its name?  Probably not 'unmanaged.lib', that would be unusual.

Comment: Seeing the linker error, I'm guessing the project is neither a static lib nor a CLR project. Need more info.

Answer (score 2):

I just started writing managed code for the first time, and had quite a time figuring out how to use my library of unmanaged classes.  But I figured out one way to do it.  And yes, you can have managed and unmanaged classes in the same library.  A complication in my case, is that my unmanaged code only compiles in VS2008, while the managed code I need to put it in, only compiles with VS2010.  So here's what I did:

1. built my unmanaged code as usual, into a static library using VS2008.  This produces MyUnmanagedClasses.lib
2. In VS 2010, right click/Properties on the (managed) project where I want to use the unmanaged code
3. Select Linker/Input
4. in the first box "Additional Dependencies", add MyUnmanagedClasses.lib
5. Select Linker/General
6. in the "Additional Library Directories" box, add the directory where MyUnmanagedClasses.lib is located
7. Use your unmanaged classes just as you always would!

Note: do NOT add the unmanaged Projects themselves into your solution--that's what I tried first, and it did not work; just link in the libraries as I stated above.

Comment: You have native code that compiles in VC2008 but not VC2010?  That's a very bad sign, usually indicates bugs in the code, since conformance improved between 2008 and 2010.